# Multiple LiveData observer call sequence

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

Let's say I have one LiveData `l` and multiple Observers `o1, o2, o3` observing on `l`. When value of `l` changes, what sequence does the observers get called? Is it the sequence that the observers are attached to `l`? Or is it non deterministic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect the former.

`LiveData` uses [`SafeIterableMap.iteratorWithAdditions()`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:lifecycle/lifecycle-livedata-core/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData.java;l=150;drc=4a302c8fadff7fefa27c7172d77d1128a2fa8f13) to iterate over its observers and notify them. The documentation described [`SafeIterableMap`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:arch/core/core-common/src/main/java/androidx/arch/core/internal/SafeIterableMap.java;l=318;drc=1b2b8e2a1dbb4f524af976c8b3c254d6dee974f9) as a "LinkedList, which pretends to be a map".

Answer (score 0):

from source code it looks like it iterates all the observers and notify them about change with data.

```
for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Observer<? super T>, ObserverWrapper>> iterator =
                        mObservers.iteratorWithAdditions(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
                    considerNotify(iterator.next().getValue());
                    if (mDispatchInvalidated) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
```